# How to check if a certain user was mentioned

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to check if a user has been mentioned (@user) in a message. This is what i currently have:

```js
    } if (message.content.includes('<@796406791323516999>')) {
        message.channel.bulkDelete(1);
        message.channel.send('User mention was detected')
    }
```

(This is wrapped in a client.on detecting when a message is sent)

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Mentions#members#has` using the member's id to check if there were any mentions, and if the member was one of the mentions.

```
const mentions = message.mentions.members;

if (!mentions) return message.channel.send('No Mentions Error Message.');

if (mentions.has('796406791323516999')) {
  message.channel.bulkDelete(1);
  message.channel.send('User mention was detected');
}
```