# How to detect if message includes any user mention?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I need that my bot detect if message content includes user mention,

Here is my code:

```
let user = message.mentions.users.first(); // As a shortcut to it
     if (message.content.startsWith(`<@${user.id}>`)) { 
        message.reply('аааа');
    } 
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a certain user was mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66625051/how-to-check-if-a-certain-user-was-mentioned)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check if there is a `user` or not by doing the following:

```js
let user = message.mentions.users.first(); // As a shortcut to it
     if (user) {
        message.reply('аааа'); // Returns message.reply() when there is a user mention
    } 

     if (!user) {
         message.reply('No user mention') // Returns if no user is mentioned     
}
});
```